How to shift files all the way left in NetBeans file tab bar?
Is there a way to shift a file all the way to the left side of the file tab bar in NetBeans when right-clicking on an opened file in the editor?
The image shows the option I am talking about. The shift left only shifts the file one file at a time. When I have a ton of files opened on the file tab bar, I would like the option to shift the file all the way to the left side without having to drag it.

Is this a possible with the "shift left" option or is it just one file at a time it shifts?
